# EXC_BAD_ACCESS on iphone

Tags: iphone, uitableview, exc-bad-access

I have the following:

**Class Number1**

.h file:

```
myAudiCiviliteInputViewController *civiliteInputViewController;
```

.m file:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [tableViewEtape4 deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO];

    civiliteInputViewController = [[myAudiCiviliteInputViewController alloc] init];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:civiliteInputViewController animated:YES];
    [civiliteInputViewController release];

    UIButton* customView = [UIButton buttonWithType: UIButtonTypeInfoLight];
    [customView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 60, 31)];
    [customView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"nc_btn_ok.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [customView addTarget:self action:@selector(okPressed) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
    UIBarButtonItem *envoyerButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView: customView];
    [self.navigationController.navigationBar.topItem setRightBarButtonItem:envoyerButton];
    [customView release];

}

-(void) okPressed{

        self.civiliteString= civiliteInputViewController.civiliteInputString;
        civiliteLabel.text = self.civiliteString;

        [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

When I click the tableView I move onto class `Number 2`.

**Class Number2 myAudiCiviliteInputViewController**

```
@synthesize civiliteInputString;

- (void)dealloc
{
    [civiliteInputString release];
    [tabelViewCivilite release];
    [tableViewArray release];
    [super dealloc];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.

    tableViewArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Madame", @"Mademoiselle", @"Monsieur", nil];

}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CellRecherchePartenaires"];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:@"CellRecherchePartenaires"] autorelease];

                    }
    // Set up the cell...
    [[cell textLabel] setText: [tableViewArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]] ;

    return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [tabelViewCivilite deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
    UITableViewCell *selectedCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    self.civiliteInputString = selectedCell.textLabel.text;

    [tableView  reloadData];

}
```

When I go from `Class Number1` to `Class Number2` it works. When I come back from `Class Number2` to `Class Number1` I get `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` in `Class Number2`, at this line:

```
[super dealloc];
```

Any ideas why?

Comment: What is tableViewCivilite in Class Number 2 ? Why are you releasing it I dont see any alloc or create or new or copy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at your code. UIButton* customView is autoreleased. Remove ->  [customView release]

```
UIButton* customView = [UIButton buttonWithType: UIButtonTypeInfoLight];
[customView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 60, 31)];
[customView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"nc_btn_ok.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[customView addTarget:self action:@selector(okPressed) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
UIBarButtonItem *envoyerButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView: customView];
[self.navigationController.navigationBar.topItem setRightBarButtonItem:envoyerButton];
[customView release]; // Remove this line
```

Answer (score 1):

1. You shouldn't `release` `customView` as it is autoreleased, remove : `[customView release];`
2. You should `release` `envoyerButton`, add : `[envoyerButton release];`

Answer (score 1):

.h file

```
myAudiCiviliteInputViewController *civiliteInputViewController;
```

.m file

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

[tableViewEtape4 deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO];
civiliteInputViewController = [[myAudiCiviliteInputViewController alloc] init];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:civiliteInputViewController animated:YES];
[civiliteInputViewController release];

UIButton* customView = [UIButton buttonWithType: UIButtonTypeInfoLight]; // Autoreleasing object 
[customView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 60, 31)];
[customView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"nc_btn_ok.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[customView addTarget:self action:@selector(okPressed) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
UIBarButtonItem *envoyerButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView: customView];
[self.navigationController.navigationBar.topItem setRightBarButtonItem:envoyerButton];
[envoyerButton release]; // You should release this object
}

-(void) okPressed
{

    self.civiliteString= civiliteInputViewController.civiliteInputString;
    civiliteLabel.text = self.civiliteString;

    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
 }
```